# Flutter Desktop - generate .exe from Mac

Tags: macos, flutter, window, flutter-desktop

I have started my journey with Flutter desktop. Till now everything was working fine. I was developing an application and it was building for the macOS like a charm. Now I would like to create the executable file for windows (.exe). Is it possible to generate one from the macOS? If so how can I achieve something like this?

EDIT:

To be able to build an executable version of the app we need to do that from the operating system that we want our app to be run on. In my case, I am using Mac on a daily basis, so I had to create the virtual machine to build the .exe for windows

Answer (score 3):

The `flutter` tool has no support for cross-compiling desktop targets, so there is no straightforward way to do what you want.

If you want to do it manually you would need to (in addition to setting up a cross-compilation toolchain for building Windows applications from macOS in general) either:

- manually recreate the pre-build steps that are normally done automatically by `flutter` (download the correct Flutter DLL and place it in the expected location, do the same with the C++ wrapper if you are using it, create the `.props` file with correct values, etc.), then build the `.sln` directly, or
- locally modify `flutter_tool` so that it doesn't do a host platform check for the Windows steps, and rewrite the way it locates `msbuild` to work on macOS.

Comment: Ok, so if I have to do something quickly it would be better to just build the app on the machine with windows.

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](https://dart.dev/tools/dart2native) says:

> **No cross-compilation support** ([issue 28617](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/issues/28617))
>
> The compiler supports creating machine code only for the operating system it’s running on. You need to run the compiler three times — on
> macOS, Windows, and Linux — to create executables for all three
> operating systems. A workaround is to use a CI (continuous
> integration) provider that supports all three operating systems.

Comment: Yeah. That is right. I had to run build on a machine with the destination operating system